# mysql - funny square characters added to the value when inserting it into table

Tags: mysql, mojibake

I have a php script that inserts values into mySQL table

`INSERT INTO stories (title) VALUES('$_REQUEST[title]);`

I checked the values of my request variables before going into the table and it's fine.

But when I add title=john to the table for example,

I get something like this:
`title = "[][][][]john"`
and when I extract the value, it's a newline then john.

I have my columns set to utf-8, I tried swedish character set as well.

Note: I don't get this error when inserting values from the phpMyAdmin commandline

Comment: I would recommend reading this article before continuing much further: "The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)" at http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `{}` around any array notation when used inside `""`.

```
$q="INSERT INTO stories(title) VALUES('{$_REQUEST['title']}')";
```

BTW, it would be better, when checking your $_REQUEST vars to store the sanitized versions in new variables, and to be sure to escape them with [`real_escape_string()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: no, {} are unnecessary here. but both quotes and escaping are needed

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: just remembered to put in the quotes around the title index. Seems to me the nested single quotes would make `{}` required. Could you explain why I'm wrong? Tx.

Comment: The OP's initial syntax `"VALUES('$_REQUEST[title]')"` (assume one quote absense was a typo) was just correct. http://php.net/types.string That's ambiguous yes, but that's correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

`SET NAMES <encoding>` query must be executed every time you connect to your database.
very simple rule.

where `<encoding>` is your HTML page encoding in mysql dialect (`utf8` for the utf-8)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the character set of the database, the server, and the client.

Note that it's not a swedish character set, it's a swedish collation.